# "flags" vars do not work because function is executing at every event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn how to validate fields with jQuery and I try to create simple plugin for this.

I have a function and I execute it on blur event of the inputs. But everytime I change the focus of the inputs, the function is running again and again and I got a new error message every time. I want to accomplish it with displaying only one message per input and doesn't matter of changing the focus multiple times.

I tried the "flags" variables approach where I have a boolean variable and when I display a message I change the flag var value. But when I walk though the inputs, blur runs the function every time from the beginning and the messages continue to appear. Here is what I have:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.myforms = function() {


        if (this.length) {

            var messageErrorVisible = false;

            if (this.val() < 2 && messageErrorVisible === false) {

                this.addClass("myforms-text-field-error");

            this.after("<span class='myforms-error-message'>Please insert value for this field</span>");

            messageErrorVisible = true;

                return this;

//    JUST some experiments but I failed with them too...            
//                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('myforms-controll-error');
//                $(this).parent().addClass('myforms-controll-error');                

//                if ($(this).parent().hassClass('myforms-controll-error')) {
//                    $('.myforms-form-controll .error-message').remove();
//                }


            }
            else {

                if (this.hasClass("myforms-text-field-error")) {
                    this.removeClass("myforms-text-field-error");
                    $('.myforms-error-message').remove();
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            console.log("There is no selector in the Markup code");
            return false;
        }
    };


}(jQuery));






$(".myforms-form-controll .myforms-text-input").blur(function() {
    $(this).myforms();
});
```

How can I display the error message only once. I once() methods didnt helped me too. And how I can remove the error message only for the field that is already filled?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT:

I created http://jsfiddle.net/65zPG/ for this code.

Comment: sorry to be a pain but could you create a jsfiddle with the basic code and html? would make editing and answering easier

Comment: I added it. Sorry. It is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle with the working code. http://jsfiddle.net/65zPG/2/

basically i have removed your boolean check as teh logic was wrong and you were resetting the value every time through the loop. Instead i have forced another check to see if the error class is present, if it is we do not add the error message again. i also changed the test to check length of val() and not just presence, but this can be changed to what ever validation you require.

The main bit of changed code is below.

hope this does what you intend, if not you may have to give more info about what you expect the code to do.

```
 if (this.val().length < 2) {
                if(!this.hasClass("myforms-text-field-error")){
                    this.addClass("myforms-text-field-error");
                    this.after("<span class='myforms-error-message'>Please insert value for this field</span>");
                }
                return this;
            }
```

Comment: Amazing! Well done! :) I am thinking of this $(this).next('span')[0].remove(); approach now. This is some kind of array containing all the span (first found from the index) elements, right? It seems that the first input does not show the error message. Is this because of the .next()?

Comment: yeah that code just makes sure that only the error message attached the that input field gets removed. if this helped feel free to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: I think I do not understand which mechanism prevents the appearing of more and more messages when I switch the focus between the inputs :)